# Changing header background to transparent when you almost or fully hit the top of the page in well known Dark Mode function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have successfully implemented the Dark Mode functionality from https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-dark-mode-on-the-web/#combining into my website. But now I want my header to change its background color (which changes depending on the mode you’re in) to transparent when it almost or fully hits the top of the page. I would like to set a scroll position.

I have found many great jsfiddles like https://jsfiddle.net/njy59/2/ that do this and add or remove a class to the header that change the background color, but I would then need to implement that functionality into my stylesheet from the Dark Mode? I don’t see how that would be possible. See my stylesheet which I have shortened to make it easier to look at and you know what I mean.

Anyone know how I can pull this off? Thank you.

Edit: I also found this Codepen (https://codepen.io/rikschennink/pen/yZYbwQ) which I have working, but it doesn’t pick my transparent color in `html:not([data-scroll='0']) {}` when I reach the top of my page. It picks the color I have above it styled onto my .header class. Which is very odd because in the example it clearly picks the right color when located at the top of the page.

I also included the Javascript below the CSS.

```
<style>
    :root {
        color-scheme: light dark; /* both supported */
    }
    
    /* DEFAULT COLORS */

    body,
    body .header {
        background: #ffffff; 
    }

    /* DARK THEME COLORS */

    body.dark-theme,
    body.dark-theme .header {
        background: #00000; 
    }

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    /* DEFAULTS TO DARK THEME */
  
    body,
    body .header {
        background: #000000; 
    }

  /* OVERRIDE DARK MODE WITH LIGHT MODE IF THE USER DECIDES TO SWAP */
  
    body.light-theme,
    body.light-theme .header {
        background: #ffffff; 
    }
  }
</style>

<script>
const dmt = document.querySelector(".dark-mode-toggle");
const prefersDarkScheme = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");

const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
if (currentTheme == "dark") {
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
} else if (currentTheme == "light") {
  document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
}

dmt.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (prefersDarkScheme.matches) {
    document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
    var theme = document.body.classList.contains("light-theme")
      ? "light"
      : "dark";
  } else {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
    var theme = document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")
      ? "dark"
      : "light";
  }
  localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one problem with your CSS.

The first bit of CSS where you have zeroes is that you only have 5, not 6. I added a thing to sense when you're at the top.

And put transparent instead of all the f's

```
<style>
    :root {
        color-scheme: light dark; /* both supported */
    }
    
    /* DEFAULT COLORS */

    body,
    body .header {
        background: #transparent; 
    }

    /* DARK THEME COLORS */

    body.dark-theme,
    body.dark-theme .header {
        background: #00000; 
    }

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    /* DEFAULTS TO DARK THEME */
  
    body,
    body .header {
        background: #000000; 
    }

  /* OVERRIDE DARK MODE WITH LIGHT MODE IF THE USER DECIDES TO SWAP */
  
    body.light-theme,
    body.light-theme .header {
        background: transparent; 
    }
  }
</style>

<script>
const dmt = document.querySelector(".dark-mode-toggle");
const prefersDarkScheme = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");

const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
if (currentTheme == "dark") {
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
} else if (currentTheme == "light") {
  document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
}

dmt.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (prefersDarkScheme.matches) {
    document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
    var theme = document.body.classList.contains("light-theme")
      ? "light"
      : "dark";
  } else {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
    var theme = document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")
      ? "dark"
      : "light";
  }
  localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
});
            var scrollPosition = $("body, html").scrollTop()
            if (scrollPosition == 0){
               // top of the page
            }
                    </script>[CHECK THIS WEBSITE OUT TO SEE IF IT'S WHAT YOU WANT! forpost.icreate.repl.co][1]
```

Comment: Hi @Carlin, but now the background is -always- transparent in Light mode. It should only be transparent when you are at the top, and #ffffff when you’ve scrolled > in Light mode. In Dark mode it should be #000000 when scrolled, and transparent when at the top.

Comment: I totally didn’t notice the code at the end of the Javascript. Thank you.